# Do you need a ticket to ride with Västtågen between Gamlestaden and Gothenburg Central Station?

Tags: public-transport, domestic-travel, gothenburg

Taking the Västtåg between the central station and Gamlestaden would be very practical for me. Do you have to get a ticket for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need a ticket. Public transportation in Gothenburg is not free. You can purchase a ticket from a machine at the station, or a manned ticket booth. The machines only take credit/debit cards. A ticket for an adult costs 30 SEK and is valid for 90 minutes on all Västtrafik lines (so train, tram, and bus).

Comment: Did the trip today and indeed you need a ticket for that route just like on the tram.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder Why is that surprising?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Arlanda Express offers free rides between the terminals of Arlanda so you never know 